# How to calculate a specific tpr (y axis) according to a specifc fpr while plotting roc curves?

Tags: python, roc

Now I want to plot roc curves, but roc_curves function in sklearn can not satisfy with my requirements. So roc in sklearn is very easy but it can not give a fpr (x axis) with a same interval, for example, fpr is 0.1, 0.2,...,1. I want to plot roc with fpr having a fixed interval. In detail, I want to get tpr values (y axis) in a specific fpr (they are 0.01,0.02,...0.09,0.1,0.0.11,0.12,...0.19,0.2).
So how to calculate a specific tpr when giving a specific fpr?
Thanks very much！

NEW！！！
I add a picture to clarify my question. Thanks!
[image]

So I want to show 20 points of for and tpr pairs. And fpr has an equal interval of 0.01. And I need to find each tpr value corresponding to each fpr (x axis and value is from 0 to 0.2, and interval between two fprs is 0.01 like the picture I have showed).
Thanks very much!

Comment: I don't understand you question. ROC curves go from 0 to 1, that's a given... Can you clarify what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @Calimo Thanks very much for commenting on my question. I have edited my question above again. So Thanks again.